# How to typeset Triforce?

Tags: symbols, fun, logos

What would be the best practice approach to typeset the [Triforce symbol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triforce) known from the Nintendo® Zelda™ series?

Comment: For those who aren't familiar with Zelda, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triforce. I imagine there's some TikZ involved.

Comment: [Newfags can't triforce](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/newfags-cant-triforce) in LaTeX?   ▲
▲ ▲

Comment: Easy. Draw a Sierpinski Triangle, but stop before you've finished.

Comment: This question combined with your avatar... it's just too much.

Comment: I wish [this tune](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IZkPREA7VV8) could be the default sound action when an answer is selected. `:)`

Comment: Also: *beware of chickens!*

Comment: I bet this question will be in this week's TeX.SX newsletter.

Comment: @Seamus at which point is a fractal "finished"? :)

Comment: @klingt.net at infinitiy. Duh.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here is a nice shaded TikZ version which you can draw in variable sizes.

[image]

You have to call the `\triforce` macro with one parameter, which is the width of the Triforce, e.g. `\triforce{10cm}`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings, calc}

\colorlet{triforcefilloutercolor}{Gold!50!Yellow}
\colorlet{triforcefillinnercolor}{white!80!triforcefilloutercolor}
\colorlet{triforceoutlineinnercolor}{white}
\colorlet{triforceoutlineoutercolor}{Goldenrod}

\tikzset{%
    triforcefillshade/.style={%
        inner color=triforcefillinnercolor,%
        outer color=triforcefilloutercolor%
    },%
    triforceoutlineshade/.style={%
        inner color=triforceoutlineinnercolor,%
        outer color=triforceoutlineoutercolor%
    }%
}

\newcommand{\triforce}[1]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}%
        \newdimen\triforcewidth%
        \newdimen\triforceheight%
        \triforcewidth=#1%
        \pgfmathparse{sqrt(3)}%
        \pgfmathsetlength{\triforceheight}{\pgfmathresult / 2 * \triforcewidth}%
        %
        \foreach \x / \y in {0 / 0, 0.5\triforcewidth / 0, 0.25\triforcewidth / 0.5\triforceheight}%
        {%
            \shade[triforcefillshade, xshift=\x, yshift=\y]%
                (0, 0)  -- +(.5\triforcewidth, 0) -- +(60:.5\triforcewidth) -- cycle;%
            \shade[triforceoutlineshade, xshift=\x, yshift=\y]%
                (0, 0)  -- +(.5\triforcewidth, 0) -- +(60:.5\triforcewidth) -- cycle%
                (30:.0175\triforcewidth) -- ($(60:.5\triforcewidth) + (-90:.0175\triforcewidth)$) -- ($(0.5\triforcewidth, 0) + (150:.0175\triforcewidth)$) -- cycle;%
        }%
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}
\triforce{10cm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hmm, I think I like this the most, because it looks pretty much like the logo on Wikipedia. I suppose I can use things like `1em` as width to make this fit into a line of text, right?

Comment: @polemon I don't think it will look as good in such a small size. Perhaps you would be better off using Heiko's answer colored black and put in a resizebox with a size of 1em.

Comment: +1 and accepted for the best looking and most cumbersome solution.

Answer (score 41):

A simple `tikz` solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\tikz\fill[yellow]
  (0,0)  -- +(1,0) -- +(60:1) -- cycle
  (1,0)  -- +(1,0) -- +(60:1) -- cycle
  (60:1) -- +(1,0) -- +(60:1) -- cycle
;
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Your answer also provides an interesting optical illusion (on my screen).  If I stare at the graphic, I see a bright yellow color.  But if I move my gaze anywhere else, the graphic color goes to a dimmer color, until I refix my gaze on the graphic.

Answer (score 11):

With stacks.  The top one is a simple stack of `\TriangleUp` symbols, whereas the bottom one uses a shrunken `\stackinset` upon the same, to achieve a border, as shown on the wiki reference.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,xcolor,bbding,graphicx}
\def\LTri{\stackinset{c}{}{c}{-.2pt}{\scalebox{.85}
  {\textcolor{yellow!20}{\TriangleUp}}}
  {\textcolor{yellow}{\TriangleUp}}}
\begin{document}
\textcolor{yellow}{\stackon[0pt]{\TriangleUp\TriangleUp}{\TriangleUp}}

\stackon[0pt]{\LTri\LTri}{\LTri}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Compile with XeLaTex :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{color}
\begin{document}
I can triforce !

\noindent
~~\ding{115}\\
\ding{115}~\ding{115}

Even in yellow:

\color{yellow}{
\noindent
~~\ding{115}\\
\ding{115}~\ding{115}
}
\end{document}
```

[image: I can triforce !]

Comment: You can't triforce! ;)

Comment: I like this solution the best

Comment: @JonathanLandrum : I think it is more in the spirit of the forum triforce ! The [one by @klingt.net](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/191562/34551) is nice, too.

Comment: It's certainly in the spirit of the "I can triforce" meme

Answer (score 8):

Just for fun, with [`pict2e`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pict2e):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pict2e}
\begin{document}
\begin{picture}(2,1.732050808)
\newsavebox{\tripart}
\savebox{\tripart}{\moveto(0,0)\lineto(1,0)\lineto(0.5,0.866025404)\closepath\fillpath}
\put(0,0){\usebox{\tripart}}
\put(1,0){\usebox{\tripart}}
\put(0.5,0.866025404){\usebox{\tripart}}
\end{picture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

## Only with `amssymb`

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
\Huge%
\hspace{-8pt}$\blacktriangle$\vspace{-15pt}\\
$\blacktriangle$\hspace{-4pt}$\blacktriangle$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Based on [Heiko Oberdiek's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/191407/34551), there is --- just for the fun --- an even simpler drawing with TiKz.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[yellow] (0,0)  -- +(2,0) -- +(60:2) -- cycle;
\fill[white]  (60:1) -- +(1,0)  -- (1,0) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

*Below the drawing with `[blue!05]` instead of `[white]`, just to mess with Steven B. Segletes's screen.*

> [image: Another triforce]

And to get a "triforce symbol logo of 1em height", as szantaii suggests :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\triforce}{\resizebox{1em}{!}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[black] (0,0)  -- +(2,0) -- +(60:2) -- cycle;
\fill[white]  (60:1) -- +(1,0)  -- (1,0) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
}}
\begin{document}
I'd like to introduce the \triforce{} symbol.
\end{document}
```

[image: I'd like to introduce the triforce symbol]

Comment: Strictly speaking, Oberdiek's answer is more correct, because of the lack of "white-out".  This is most evident when the output is in PNG format.

Comment: @Clément I agree with bug's comment. Try using path clipping combined with TikZ's _even odd rule_ instead of white filling the unnecessary area. See section _15.9 Clipping and Fading (Soft Clipping)_ in the TikZ & PGF manual (version 3.0.0). Example: `\begin{tikzpicture}[even odd rule] \clip (0, 0) -- +(2, 0) -- +(60:2) -- cycle (1, 0) -- +(60:1) -- +(120:1) -- cycle; \fill (0, 0) -- +(2, 0) -- +(60:2) -- cycle; \end{tikzpicture}`.

Comment: You are both right. This is a community wiki, feel free to edit!

Comment: @Clément: Thank you very much for creating this. I've just added it to my symbol classifier website ([link](http://write-math.com/symbol/?id=1715), it wasn't added to the classifier as I guess not many people will need it)